# Flutter children widget... Is there a difference?

Tags: flutter, material-design

The output of the two codes below seem to be the same. So is there a difference between omitting < Widget > or not?

```
return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: Image.asset('images/dice1.png'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Image.asset('images/dice1.png'),
        ),
```

and

```
return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: Image.asset('images/dice1.png'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Image.asset('images/dice1.png'),
        ),
```

Comment: Right now, Both the code contains `<Widget>`.

Answer (score 0):

If anything other than a [`StatefulWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) or [`StatelessWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html) is passed in the list of `children` of `Row`, `Column` or any widget that expects only widgets, then it will throw an error -

> The element type 'Not a Widget' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'